# Undoing jQuery insertBefore / After

Tags: jquery

I am moving some `div` elements around when the browser screen is narrow which works well, but I want to revert the changes when the browser screen gets wider again. How can I revert the changes?

```js
function mobileNavOrderingChanges() {
  var windowWidthEquals = $(window).width();

  if (windowWidthEquals <= 600) {
    $("#footer-outer .FooterCol_General_Content").insertBefore("#footer-outer .FooterCol_FollowUs_Content");
    $("#footer-outer .footerCol_WorkWithUs").insertBefore("#footer-outer .FooterCol_FollowUs_Content");
    $("#footer-outer .footerCol_WorkWithUs_Content").insertBefore("#footer-outer .FooterCol_FollowUs_Content");
    $("#footer-outer .footerCol_FollowUs").insertBefore("#footer-outer .FooterCol_FollowUs_Content");
  } else if (windowWidthEquals >= 601) {
    {
      // reset order back to normal - BUT HOW???
    }
  }
}

mobileNavOrderingChanges();

$(window).resize(function() {
  mobileNavOrderingChanges();
});
```

Comment: Don't use JS for this. Use [CSS `@media` queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Media_queries), then you will get the functionality you require by default. I realise that you're moving elements around the DOM in the JS, but you can use fixed positioning in CSS to proxy this behaviour.

Comment: Fixed positioning is *far* more trouble that it is worth when you use it on a large scale. Use CSS Grid for this.

Comment: I dont really have the option to change the markup as its set. Need to do it via jQuery

Comment: @Quentin very true - I was suggesting a quick fix in this case as I doubt the HTML in this case would be built using grid. You're 100% correct though.

Comment: If you must go down this route, use `.insertBefore` (or other method) to put it back where it was.  You'll need to be able to locate where it was, which you've not provided.   eg `$("#footer-outer .FooterCol_General_Content").insertAfter("#footer_general_original_location")` where Footer_general_original_location could just be an empty div `<div id='Footer_general_original_location'></div>`

Comment: This issues I am having using insertBefore / insertAfter in the over 601 statement is that becase I've moved them - they wont move back correctly - they have moved Div parents as they all sit in nested div heirachy - bit of a mess - but its the way the markup is which i cant change...

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this.... I had a typo on one of the classnames which meant the DIV I wanted to move would not move... doh!